# SQLAlchemy model inheritance without relations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I want to create two similar tables. I need not to create any realtions between them.

```
    class Table1(Base):
         __tablename__ = "table1"
         id = Column(UUIDType, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
         value = Column(String(70), nullable=True)
    
     class Table2(Table1):
         __tablename__ = "table2"
         unit = Column(String(10), nullable=True)
```

But when I try to use that models I get

```
E   sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't determine the inherit condition between inherited table 'table1' and inheriting table 'table2';
```

Is it possible to refuse automatic creation of the relations without abstract class usage?

Comment: Have a read of https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html, it shows all the different ways you can do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if by:

> without abstract class usage

you meant avoiding [abstract-concrete-classes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html#abstract-concrete-classes), if so the solution that worked for me was using [declarative_mixins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html), so in your case this would be:

```
class TableBase(object):
    id = Column(UUIDType, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    value = Column(String(70), nullable=True)

class Table1(TableBase, Base):
    __tablename__ = "table1"

class Table2(TableBase, Base):
    __tablename__ = "table2"
    unit = Column(String(10), nullable=True)
```